# Missing folders in Thunderbird

Tags: windows-7, windows, thunderbird

I upgraded Thunderbird from 9 to 10 and now folders are missing.

In my Local Folders I had a folder named "Backup2". It no longer shows in Thunderbird.

But when I go to `%APPDATA%\Thunderbird\Profiles\default\Mail\Local Folders` I can see `Backup2.sbd` folder with all the subfolders inside. How to get Thunderbird to show it in the UI?

Other folders such as `Backup` and `Backup3` are still working OK.

Comment: @Psycogeek - It is Windows 7. I will try what you suggested.

Comment: @Psycogeek - I mistyped it. Fixed now.

Comment: @Psycogeek - Your profile may be not "default"?

Comment: OK I found out how. I simply made a "New Folder" inside Thunderbird at the spot the missing foders were supposed to be and they magically appeared with all emails intact! I am not sure why Thunderbird 10 did not see them but anyway it works now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. I went into Thunderbird after backing up the profile folder, and made a "New Folder" at the location of the missing folder and gave it the same name. It was created and appeared with all the missing emails contained in it.